# Adjusting term faces in the new Emacs 24.3

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

How can I adjust the `term` face in the new Emacs to get the same control that was possible with `ansi-term-color-vector`?

One of the [new features](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/03/11/whats-new-emacs-24-3/) in Emacs 24.3 seems to be that it revamps the mechanism to control the face of `term` buffers, i.e.:

> The variables `term-default-fg-color` and `term-default-bg-color` are now
>   deprecated in favor of the customizable face `term`.
>
> You can customize how to display ANSI terminal colors and styles by
>   customizing the corresponding `term-color-COLOR`, `term-color-underline`
>   and `term-color-bold` faces.

Mickey from Mastering Emacs [comments the following](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/03/11/whats-new-emacs-24-3/):

> If, like me, you customized `ansi-color-names-vector` to change the
>   default term colours I suggest you switch to using the faces now. The
>   good news here is you can, should desire to, change more than just the
>   colours for each ANSI Color: there’s nothing stopping you from forcing
>   a different font for certain colours

Like Mickey, I was also using `ansi-color-names-vector` to make sure that the color of my `term` buffers looked well on dark themes (e.g. `tango-dark`)

```
(setq ansi-term-color-vector [unspecified “black” “red3” “lime green” “yellow3” “DeepSkyBlue?3” “magenta3” “cyan3” “white”])
```

But this now results in an error:

```
"error in process filter: Invalid face; unspecified"
```

In an attempt to use the new face `term`, when I go to `M-x describe-face term`, I see the following:

```
[] Font Family
[] Font Foundry
[] Width
[] Height
[] Weight
[] Slant
[] Underline
[] Overline
[] Strike-through
[] Box around text
[] Inverse-video
[] Foreground
[] Background
[] Stipple
[x]  Inherit
```

But how do I adjust these settings to get the same effect I achieved using `ansi-term-color-vector`?

### Update

I am still unable to fix the colors. Here is the menu that I get for `M-x customize-theme tango-dark`:

[image]

And here is an example of one of the colors/faces in a terminal that are hard to see:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me in Emacs 24.3.1 to set the colors of term and ansi-term. Just change the colors to your preferred values (with the background adjusted accordingly).

```
;; term
(defface term-color-black 
  '((t (:foreground "#3f3f3f" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-red
  '((t (:foreground "#cc9393" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-green
  '((t (:foreground "#7f9f7f" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-yellow
  '((t (:foreground "#f0dfaf" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-blue 
  '((t (:foreground "#6d85ba" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-magenta 
  '((t (:foreground "#dc8cc3" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-cyan
  '((t (:foreground "#93e0e3" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
(defface term-color-white
  '((t (:foreground "#dcdccc" :background "#272822"))) 
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
'(term-default-fg-color ((t (:inherit term-color-white))))
'(term-default-bg-color ((t (:inherit term-color-black))))

;; ansi-term colors
(setq ansi-term-color-vector
  [term term-color-black term-color-red term-color-green term-color-yellow 
    term-color-blue term-color-magenta term-color-cyan term-color-white])
```

Answer (score 5):

In Emacs 24.3 you'll need to adjust the following faces:

```
   ;; term
   `(term-color-black ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-bg
                                       :background ,zenburn-bg-1))))
   `(term-color-red ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-red-2
                                       :background ,zenburn-red-4))))
   `(term-color-green ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-green
                                       :background ,zenburn-green+2))))
   `(term-color-yellow ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-orange
                                       :background ,zenburn-yellow))))
   `(term-color-blue ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-blue-1
                                      :background ,zenburn-blue-4))))
   `(term-color-magenta ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-magenta
                                         :background ,zenburn-red))))
   `(term-color-cyan ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-cyan
                                       :background ,zenburn-blue))))
   `(term-color-white ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg
                                       :background ,zenburn-fg-1))))
   '(term-default-fg-color ((t (:inherit term-color-white))))
   '(term-default-bg-color ((t (:inherit term-color-black))))
```

This code is from the latest version of [Zenburn](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs).
Personally I feel that the new way of customising the faces is an improvement over the use of the obscure vector.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts or pointers on how I could do this for a theme like `tango-dark`?  (i.e. how can I find out the different colors supported by my theme? such as `zenburn-bg-1`, etc. but for `tango-dark`)

Comment: Just do a `M-x describe-theme tango-dark` and see the colour definitions in `tango-dark-theme.el`.

Comment: Thanks @Bodzhidar. I am sure you are right that I could follow your steps to fix this problem, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to make it work for `tango-dark`. It looks like `tango-dark` already sets `ansi-color-names-vector` to a given set of colors in `tango-dark.el` (see the code here: `http://fossies.org/unix/misc/emacs-24.3.tar.gz:a/emacs-24.3/etc/themes/tango-dark-theme.el`). Moreover, these colors seem to look fine when I look up `M-x describe-theme tango-tark` (see the images I posted in the OP), but for some reason they don't work well in terminals.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is why your background colors in zenburn (the ones you defined above) are different for each `term-color` (shouldn't they be set to inherit the background color of the terminal?)

Comment: For each color you need a ligher foreground version and a darker background version. That's how the faces were defined in term.el(it's not something I inventited for zenburn) itself. Nothing in term actually uses those faces directly, they are just used to derive other faces.

Comment: Pasting this at the right place in the theme.el file worked. I had to remove `ansi-color-names-vector` and `ansi-term-color-vector` manually from `.emacs.d/init.el`. Running `customize-group` on `term` recreates them, then it breaks again and I must remove the lines once more. I am on emacs 25.0.50.2.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `term` <kbd>RET</kbd>
as the easiest entry point to customizing those colours.