# Emacs: Have a completely different background-color in ansi-term

Tags: emacs, background-color, emacs24, ansi-term

I'm normally using a light background color in all my Emacs faces. But I'm used to dark backgrounds in a terminal. Therefore I wanted to set the background color of ansi-term to black. However when I do this only the part where text has already been written to is colored correctly, the rest of the background is still light as in other faces. I'm looking for a way to completely set the background color of ansi-term to black. 
An example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3pra.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [color-theme-buffer-local](https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local). I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Default face / font, unless another definition overrides it:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "black" :foreground "white"
    :font "Courier" :height 180)
```

See also:    [Adjusting term faces in the new Emacs 24.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661372/adjusting-term-faces-in-the-new-emacs-24-3)

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/ansi-term.png))</sub>