# Colors in Emacs multi-term

Tags: emacs, terminal

I get basically the same colors in an Emacs terminal as inside gnome-terminal. But some of the colors in Emacs are too dark. For instance, a light blue appears as dark blue in Emacs. How can I customize the terminal colors so they match what I get in gnome-terminal?

Comment: Here is a related thread that may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661372/adjusting-term-faces-in-the-new-emacs-24-3

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18027804/439332) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

M-x customize will allow you to change all of the colors within emacs.

Comment: I had to customize `ansi-term-color-vector`.